# How to replace one pandas dataframe column values based on some other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. `df1` and `df2`. This is the content of `df1`

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    1    12   100
1    2    34   200
2    3    56   300
3    4    78   400
```

This is the content of `df2`

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    2  1984   500
1    3  4891   600
```

I want to have this final data frame:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    1    12   100
1    2  1984   200
2    3  4891   300
3    4    78   400
```

*Note that `col1` is the primary key in `df1` and `df2`*. I tried to do it via mapping values, but I could not make it work.

Here is an MCVE  for checking those data frames easily:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['1', '2','3','4'], 'col2': [12, 34,56,78],'col3':[100,200,300,400]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d = {'col1': ['2','3'], 'col2': [1984,4891],'col3':[500,600]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df1)
print(df2)
d = {'col1': ['1', '2','3','4'], 'col2': [12, 1984,4891,78],'col3':[100,200,300,400]}
df_final = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df_final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` and `fillna`:

```
df1['col2'] = (df1['col1']
               .map(df2.set_index('col1')['col2'])
               .fillna(df1['col2'], downcast='infer')
              )
```

output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    1    12   100
1    2  1984   200
2    3  4891   300
3    4    78   400
```

Answer (score 1):

If `col1` is unique, [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) is an option, too:

```py
>>> (df2.drop("col3", axis=1)
        .set_index("col1")
        .combine_first(df1.set_index("col1"))
        .reset_index()
    )
  col1  col2  col3
0    1    12   100
1    2  1984   200
2    3  4891   300
3    4    78   400
```